# Why does Data.Set require elements to be an instance of Ord?

Tags: haskell, set

This doesn't work

```
data Cutlery = Knife | Fork deriving (Show,Eq)
let x = [Knife,Fork]
let set1 = Set.fromList x
```

while defining

```
data Cutlery = Knife | Fork deriving (Show,Ord,Eq)
```

solves the issue but doesn't make sense. Is Data.Set different than the mathematical definition of a set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `Data.Set` captures the mathematical abstraction of a set, but it is not identical. The main difference is that a `Data.Set` requires its elements to be ordered, whereas a mathematical set only requires that its elements be comparable for equality.

The reason for requiring `Ord` is efficiency. It would be perfectly possible to build a set abstraction by defining

```
data Set a = Set [a]
```

i.e. under the hood it is just a list, and we make sure we never insert duplicate elements. The `elem` and `insert` operations would be

```
elem a (Set as) = any (a ==) as

insert a (Set as) | a `elem` as = Set as
                  | otherwise   = Set (a:as)
```

However, this means that both `elem` and `insert` are O(*n*) operations. If we want to do any better than this, the standard approaches are

1. Store the elements in a balanced binary tree (which requires an `Ord` instance)
2. Hash the elements and store them in an array (which requires a `Hashable` instance).

### TreeSet

The implementation chosen by the authors of `Data.Set` was to use a binary tree, which you can see by going to the [source](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/src/Data-Set-Base.html#Set). The implementation is more or less

```
data Set a = Bin a (Set a) (Set a)
           | Tip
```

Now you can write the `elem` function as

```
elem :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Bool
elem = go
  where
    go _  Tip = False
    go x (Bin y l r) = case compare x y of
      LT -> go x l
      GT -> go x r
      EQ -> True
```

which is an O(log *n*) operation, rather than O(*n*). Insertions are trickier (as you need to keep the tree balanced) but similar.

### HashSet

In a hash set, you don't directly compare elements when inserting and removing them. Instead, each element is *hashed* to an integer, and stored in a location based on that integer.

In theory this doesn't require an `Ord` instance. In practice, you need some method of keeping track of multiple elements that hash to the same value, and the method chosen by the developers of `Data.HashSet` is to store multiple elements in a regular `Data.Set`, so it turns out you *do* need the `Ord` instance after all!

```
data HashSet a = HashSet (Data.IntMap.IntMap (Data.Set.Set a))
```

It could have been written instead as

```
data HashSet a = HashSet (Data.IntMap.IntMap [a])
```

instead, which removes out the `Ord` requirement at the cost of some inefficiency if there are many elements which has to the same value.

Comment: In comparison to Java say there is a HashSet and a TreeSet where the elements of a TreeSet are comparable but the elements in a HashSet are not. Should Haskell employ a similar approach?

Comment: @medPhys-pl: the elements of HashSet need to be hashable. This is true for [the Haskell implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.3.0.1/docs/Data-HashSet.html) as well as for the Java one, only I reckon Java cheats by hashing _memory adresses_, which Haskell shuns because it's unsafe (identical values may have different hashes).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Actually, in Java, the `Object` class has the `hashCode` and  `equals` methods, and `HashMap`/`HashSet` use those; you're supposed to override them in order to get correct behavior with hash-based collections. This leads to three of the most common bugs I see among Java newcomers: (a) not knowing or forgetting to implement `hashCode` and `equals` for your map keys; (b) implementing the `hashCode` method incorrectly; and (c) implementing `hashCode` as `return toString().hashCode()`, with horrible performance...

Comment: Another option is to use some sort of trie.

Answer (score 7):

> Is `Data.Set` different than the mathematical definition of a set?

Obviously, mathematical sets can be uncountable infinite – you won’t be able to represent that in all generality with a computer, or even a Turing machine.

But the answer you are looking for is this: `Data.Set` is a data type based on binary trees, and needs a total linear order on the elements to know whether to put and later find something on the left or right subtree of a node. So while it would be possible to implement a set datatype without an `Ord` constraint, this particular, more efficient implementation would not.

Answer (score 1):

Data.HashSet if you want an unordered set:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.1.4.6/docs/Data-HashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

It's for efficiency. `Data.Set` is implemented as a **binary search tree** (aka **ordered** or **sorted binary trees**). Using this data structure means that we can write a lookup function, [`member`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html#v:member), that  takes *logarithmic* time, O(logn) time, instead of what would be *linear time*, O(n). By ordering the elements, we can perform exponentially less comparisons when performing lookups.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree):

> Binary search trees keep their keys in *sorted order*, so that lookup and other operations can use the principle of *binary search*. ... each lookup, insertion or deletion takes time proportional to the *logarithm of the number of items* stored in the tree.

If the elements were not an instance of `Ord`, there would not be a way to order the binary search tree elements -- we'd only be able to form a binary tree, not a binary search tree. As a result, we would not be able to get quick lookup times.